# slide out and mouse outside glitch jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/9spzQ/9/).

The problem is that, when you click on the button to close the slide out box, there is a glitch. I don't know how to fix it.

If someone could help me out that would be great. thanks!

```
var mouse_is_inside = false;

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#box').hover(function(){ 
                mouse_is_inside=true; 
            }, function(){ 
                mouse_is_inside=false; 
            });
            $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
                if(! mouse_is_inside) $('#box').slideUp();
            });
        });
```

That's the code, if it helps anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead:

```
$(".show").click(function(){
    $("#box").slideToggle();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9spzQ/10/

Comment: Oh haha! That was easy. Thanks a lot!